# How to make my view stick to the right of the window?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I want to "align" my view to the right of my window, without resizing. I put in the code below

```
tableContainer.autoresizingMask = NSViewHeightSizable | NSViewLayerContentsPlacementRight;
```

but it always resizes my views width. I just want to create a view whose width stays the same and always sticks to the right of the window. So just like the panels in Photoshop for example. How do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the right constants for your `autoresizingMask`. The `NSViewLayerContentsPlacementRight` enumeration is to be used with the `setLayerContentsPlacement:` method, not with the `setAutoresizingMask:` method as you do.

The value for the `autoresizingMask` property of `NSView` is a bitwise-OR combination of [the following values, according to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Resizing_masks).

So for your purpose, you need to use **`NSViewMinXMargin`** (and not `NSViewLayerContentsPlacementRight`) so that the left margin will be flexible, but not the right margin, and so that when resizing your superview, your view will keep the distance of the right border fixed, thus keeping it on the right of its superview.

Of course, if you want the height of your view to resize along with its superview's height as you seem to, use this `NSViewMinXMargin` in bitwise-OR combination with `NSViewHeightSizable`

```
tableContainer.autoresizingMask = NSViewHeightSizable | NSViewMinXMargin;
```